# SQL - How the combination of 13 numeric columns equate to 1 column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with 14 numeric columns. Somehow; either by adding, subtracting or ignoring each of the first 13 columns, I want the combination to equal the 14th column. I want to find out what needs to be added, what needs to be subtracted and what needs to be ignored to get the 14th column.

For example if I had 6 columns (instead of 14) the solution could be 
COLUMN1 + COLUMN2 - COLUMN3 + (0*COLUMN4) + COLUMN5

So that when I run:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE 
WHERE COLUMN1 + COLUMN2 - COLUMN3 + (0*COLUMN4) + COLUMN5 != COLUMN6
```

I get 0.

What's the most efficient way of achieving this? I'm willing to let this run for a few hours if necessary.

I'm using SQL server 2016

Answer (score 2):

This is an entirely new answer.

The idea is to unpivot and then rejoin a bunch of times.  Here is an example with 3 columns rather than 13:

```
with tcols as (
      select t.id, t.col14, v.which, v.col, v2.sign
      from t cross apply
           (values (1, t.col1), (2, t.col2), (3, t.col3)) v(which, col) cross apply
           (values (-1), (1), (0)) v2(sign)
     )
select *
from tcols tc1 join
     tcols tc2
     on tc2.id = tc1.id and tc1.which = 1 and tc2.which = 2 join
     tcols tc3
     on tc3.id = tc2.id and tc3.which = 3
where (tc1.sign * tc1.col) + (tc2.sign * tc2.col) + (tc3.sign * tc3.col) = tc1.col14;
```

Obviously extending this requires adding more joins.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b1acbbd5daeedb586f0f8edc8af0dbc3) is a db<>fiddle

Will this work on 13 columns?  The number of comparisons for each id is 3^13 = 1,594,323.  That is a lot but probably not beyond the pale for modern databases.

Comment: sorry I should have specified that I'm running this on SQL server 2016. Fortunately I have a string_agg function but I don't think cross applying values like that works. Should I simply create a table like so: select 1,col1 from t union all select 2,col2 from t etc.?

Comment: The idea is very good. But as is the query would sum up -col1 +col1 -col2 +col2 ... I.e. the query doesn't decide for one sign to try with, but takes all three always ending up with a sum of 0.

Comment: @Anonymous . . . Of course `cross apply`ing works in SQL Server 2016.  It has been in SQL Server for a long, long time.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but unfortunately my string_agg function (in SQL Server 2016) doesn't work as well as the official 2017 function so unfortunately I can't run this.

Comment: @Anonymous . . . For this application there are alternatives to `string_agg()`.  They are just more verbose.

Comment: @GordonLinoff thank you for the edit, unfortunately this still isn't quite giving me the result I'm looking for. This simply sets all the parameters to 1 which isn't correct.I even created a small table consisting of 6 columns to test this and the parameters were simply 11111. Any idea why this might be the case?

Comment: Is the ID column simply a row number that I should add to the original table? At the moment my table consists 14 numeric columns (of which 13 combine to make the 14th) and that's it, there are no other columns.

Comment: @Anonymous . . . The original answer was fraught with "wishful programming".  I've totally modified the answer and included a (reduced) db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to get all possible faktors of -1, 0, and 1 per position first. E.g.:

```
-1, -1, -1, -1, -1
-1, -1, -1, -1,  0
-1, -1, -1, -1, +1
-1, -1, -1,  0, -1
-1, -1, -1,  0,  0
-1, -1, -1,  0, +1
...
```

Then multiply each factor with each value and see if you get the desired result.

I am using a recursive query to build the factors. For simplicity I am using six values (five operands and one result) here.

```
with singlefactors (factor) as
(
  select -1 union all select 0 union all select 1
)
, cte (f1, f2, f3, f4, f5, num) as
(
  select factor, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 from singlefactors
  union all
  select
    cte.f1,
    case when cte.num = 1 then singlefactors.factor else cte.f2 end,
    case when cte.num = 2 then singlefactors.factor else cte.f3 end,
    case when cte.num = 3 then singlefactors.factor else cte.f4 end,
    case when cte.num = 4 then singlefactors.factor else cte.f5 end,
    cte.num + 1
  from cte
  cross join singlefactors
  where cte.num < 5
)
, factors as
(
  select f1, f2, f3, f4, f5 from cte where num = 5
)
select *
from mytable m
join factors f on m.col1 * f.f1 + m.col2 * f.f2 +
                  m.col3 * f.f3 + m.col4 * f.f4 +
                  m.col5 * f.f5 = m.col6
order by m.col1, m.col2, m.col3, m.col4, m.col5, m.col6, f.f1, f.f2, f.f3, f.f4, f.f5;
```

**Result:**

```
+ -----+------+------+------+------+------+----+----+----+----+----+
| col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5 | col6 | f1 | f2 | f3 | f4 | f5 |
+ -----+------+------+------+------+------+----+----+----+----+----+
| 1    | 2    | 3    | 4    | 5    | 6    | -1 | -1 |  0 |  1 |  1 |
| 1    | 2    | 3    | 4    | 5    | 6    | -1 |  0 |  1 |  1 |  0 |
| 1    | 2    | 3    | 4    | 5    | 6    | -1 |  1 |  0 |  0 |  1 |
| ...  |      |      |      |      |      |    |    |    |    |    |
+ -----+------+------+------+------+------+----+----+----+----+----+
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=872201f49f9cace4ad62be59465bca87

You probably want the result to look somewhat nicer, but that shouldn't be too complicated to accomplish from here.

Answer (score 0):

You try?

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE WHERE ((COLUMN1 + (COLUMN2 - (COLUMN3 + (0*COLUMN4)))) + COLUMN5) != COLUMN6
```

Maybe make trouble for sum and substraction